# SQL Queries - Count total of rows with Case when statement

Tags: sql, subquery

I will like to count to get the correct number of rows when the [Location] column match a certain value.
Below is my table:

| Student | Marks | Location | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kenn | 66 | UK | 09-01-2022 |
| Kenn | 89 | UK | 09-01-2022 |
| Kenn | 77 | Canada | 09-01-2022 |

Below SQL queries is what I have tried:

```
  SELECT [Student]
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN  [Location] = 'UK' THEN [Marks] ELSE 0 END) AS UK
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN  [Location] = 'Canada' THEN [Marks] ELSE 0 END) AS Canada
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY [Student]
```

But the output is

| Student | UK | Canada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kenn | 3 | 3 |

What I expected to see is:

| Student | UK | Canada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kenn | 2 | 1 |

Please advise if anything wrong with my SQL queries?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sum instead

```
SELECT [Student]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [Location] = 'UK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UK
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [Device] = 'Canada' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Canada
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY [Student]
```